Footer overlapping with content on mobile version
I have a problem on the main page of the site. On the desktop version everything looks good, but on the mobile version the footer is not at the very bottom and covers the elements. How to fix this? I will be very grateful for every answer.
I think the problem is in the mobile styles (from line 704 to line 928)
Website: https://gta-fandom.com/home
Mobile Version


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="google-adsense-account" content="ca-pub-9285651055717731">
  <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-9285651055717731" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-NK8M80SQWB"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'G-NK8M80SQWB');
  </script>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>GTA 6 Wiki</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@100..700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="description" content="Welcome to GTA 6 Wiki! Here you can find all the information about GTA 6, including a comprehensive wiki, the latest news, and a gallery of the game's best moments.">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <style>
    /* Общие стили для мобильной версии */
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      main {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0 !important;
        flex-grow: 1;
        margin-left: -10px !important;
        margin-right: -10px !important;
        height: auto !important;
      }

      .welcome-box {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
        padding: 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 8px;
        margin-top: 20px !important;
        padding: 15px !important;
        text-align: center;
        width: 130%;
        /* Ширина центрального окна */
        height: 160px !important;
        align-items: center !important;
        justify-items: center !important;
      }

      #article-count {
        font-size: 16px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }

      #last-activity {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }

      .section-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        gap: 5px;
        margin: 0 5px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-items: center;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .section {
        height: 160px;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 140px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .section img {
        height: 80px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }

      .section h2 {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }

      .section p {
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 1.2;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        padding: 0 5px;
      }

      .left-sidebar,
      .right-sidebar {
        width: 90%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .news-box,
      .recommendations-box {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .information-buttons button,
      .random-buttons button {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      .latest-news-item img {
        height: 100px;
      }

      .recommended-item {
        width: calc(50% - 5px);
        margin: 5px;
      }

      .recommended-item img {
        height: 70px;
      }

      .main-content h1 {
        font-size: 20px !important;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
      }

      .main-content h2 {
        font-size: 19px !important;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
      }

      .main-content #article-count {
        font-size: 15px !important;
        line-height: 1.3;
      }

      .main-content #last-activity {
        font-size: 11px !important;
      }

      .section-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        /* Два окошка в ряд */
        gap: 10px !important;
        /* Уменьшаем отступы между секциями */
        align-items: center !important;
        margin-left: 10px !important;
        /* Расстояние до левого края */
        margin-right: 10px !important;
        justify-items: center;
        /* Центрируем карточки по горизонтали */
        gap: 5px !important;
        margin-top: 0px !important;
        margin-bottom: 50px;

      }

      .section {
        height: 210px;
        /* Ещё уменьшаем высоту секций */
        padding: 8px;
        /* Уменьшаем внутренние отступы */
        width: 160px;
        /* Секция занимает всю ширину колонки */
      }

      .section img {
        height: 100px;
        /* Уменьшаем высоту изображений */
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        /* Уменьшаем отступ от изображения до текста */
      }

      .section h2 {
        font-size: 14px;
        /* Ещё уменьшаем заголовки */
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
        /* Уменьшаем отступ после заголовка */
      }

      .section p {
        font-size: 11px;
        /* Уменьшаем текст описания */
        line-height: 1.2;
        margin-bottom: 20px !important;
        padding: 5px;
      }

      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .footer {
        margin-top: auto !important;
        /* автоматически перемещается вниз */
        height: auto !important;
      }

      .content {
        margin-top: 50px;
        padding: 0 0px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        height: auto !important;

      }

      .right-sidebar .random-buttons {
        margin-bottom: 100px !important;
      }

      body {
        display: flex !important;
        flex-direction: column !important;
        align-items: center !important;
      }

      main {
        flex: 1 1 auto !important;
        /*grow vertically*/
      }

      main {
        flex-grow: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .footer {
        position: static;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #1b1b1b;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center !important;
        padding: 10px;
        justify-content: end !important;
        align-items: end !important;
        margin-top: 500px !important;
        height: 300px !important;
      }

      .header {
        height: 300px !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="photos/logo.png" alt="GTA 6 Wiki">
    </div>
    <nav class="nav">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="explore.html">Explore</a>
      <a href="trailers.html">Trailers</a>
      <a href="news.html">News</a>
      <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
      <a href="donate.html">Donate</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="search-container">
      <input type="text" id="searchQuery" placeholder="Search...">
      <button id="searchButton"></button>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main style="position: relative; margin-bottom: 200px;">
    <div class="left-sidebar">
      <div class="news-box">
        <h3>Latest News</h3>
        <div id="latest-news">
          <!-- Новости будут добавлены динамически -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="information-buttons" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <h3 style="align-items: center !important ; text-align:center !important ;">Information</h3>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='/privacy-policy.html'">Privacy Policy</button>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='/about.html'">About GTA 6 Wiki</button>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='/contact.html'">Contact Us</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content" style="align-items: center !important; ">
      <div class="welcome-box">
        <h1>Welcome to GTA 6 Wiki</h1>
        <p id="article-count"><span>Currently, there are </span><a href="explore.html" id="article-number">xxx</a> about the world of GTA 6</p>
        <p id="last-activity">Last update: December 28, 2024 1:05</p>
      </div>
      <h2>Explore GTA 6 World</h2>
      <div class="section-container" style="align-items: center !important; justify-content: center !important;">
        <a href="explore/characters.html" class="section">
                <img src="assets/bonny.jpg" alt="GTA 6 Characters">
                <h2>Characters</h2>
                <p>Explore all the characters from the world of GTA 6.</p>
            </a>
        <a href="explore/vehicles.html" class="section">
                <img src="explore/img/Vehicles.png" alt="GTA 6 Vehicles">
                <h2>Vehicles</h2>
                <p>Explore all vehicles featured in the world of GTA 6.</p>
            </a>
        <a href="explore/locations.html" class="section">
                <img src="explore/img/buildings.png" alt="GTA 6 Locations">
                <h2>Locations</h2>
                <p>Explore all the locations from the world of GTA 6.</p>
            </a>
        <a href="explore/weapons.html" class="section">
                <img src="explore/img/weapons.jpg" alt="GTA 6 Weapons">
                <h2>Weapons</h2>
                <p>Explore all the types of weapons featured in GTA 6.</p>
            </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right-sidebar" style="margin-top: 200px;">
      <div class="recommendations-box" style="margin-top: 15px !important;" style="height: auto !important;">
        <h3>Recommended</h3>
        <div id="recommended-articles" style="gap: 10px !important; ">
          <!-- Рекомендованные статьи будут вставляться сюда -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="random-buttons" style="height: auto !important;">
        <h3>Random Choice</h3>
        <button id="random-article">Random Article</button>
        <button id="random-news">Random News</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer class="footer">
    <p>&copy; 2024 GTA 6 Wiki. All rights reserved.</p>
    <p>This is an unofficial fan site, not affiliated with Rockstar Games. <span class="mobile-br"></span>GTA 6 and related assets are trademarks of Rockstar Games.</p>
  </footer>
  <script>
    // Загрузка статей и подсчёт их количества
    fetch('/pages.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const articles = data; // Массив статей из pages.json
        const articleCount = articles.length; // Подсчёт количества статей

        // Обновляем текст с количеством статей
        document.getElementById('article-number').innerText = `${articleCount} articles`;
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching pages.json:', error));

    // Загрузка статей и отображение рекомендованных
    fetch('/pages.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const articles = data; // Массив статей из pages.json

        // Находим статью с названием "State of Leonida"
        const leonidaArticle = articles.find(article => article.title === "State of Leonida");

        if (leonidaArticle) {
          const recommendedContainer = document.getElementById('recommended-articles');

          // Очищаем контейнер на случай перезаписи
          recommendedContainer.innerHTML = '';

          // Добавляем карточку "State of Leonida" первой
          const leonidaElement = document.createElement('div');
          leonidaElement.classList.add('recommended-item');
          leonidaElement.innerHTML = `
                    <img src="${leonidaArticle.photo}" alt="${leonidaArticle.title}" class="recommended-item-img">
                    <h3>${leonidaArticle.title}</h3>
                `;
          leonidaElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.location.href = leonidaArticle.link;
          });
          recommendedContainer.appendChild(leonidaElement);

          // Убираем "State of Leonida" из общего списка
          const otherArticles = articles.filter(article => article.title !== "State of Leonida");

          // Добавляем ровно 2 случайные статьи
          const randomArticles = getRandomArticles(otherArticles, 2);
          randomArticles.forEach(article => {
            const articleElement = document.createElement('div');
            articleElement.classList.add('recommended-item');
            articleElement.innerHTML = `
                        <img src="${article.photo}" alt="${article.title}" class="recommended-item-img">
                        <h3>${article.title}</h3>
                    `;
            articleElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
              window.location.href = article.link;
            });
            recommendedContainer.appendChild(articleElement);
          });
        } else {
          console.error('State of Leonida article not found in pages.json');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching pages.json:', error));

    // Функция для выбора случайных статей
    function getRandomArticles(articles, count) {
      return articles
        .sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()) // Перемешиваем статьи
        .slice(0, count); // Берём первые `count` элементов
    }

    // Загрузка и отображение новостей
    fetch('/articles.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        // Сортируем новости по дате (от самых новых к старым)
        const sortedNews = data.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date));
        const latestNews = sortedNews.slice(0, 3); // Берем три самых новых новости

        const newsContainer = document.getElementById('latest-news');
        latestNews.forEach(news => {
          const newsItem = document.createElement('div');
          newsItem.classList.add('latest-news-item');

          newsItem.innerHTML = `
                    <img src="${news.image}" alt="${news.title}">
                    <h4>${news.title}</h4>
                    <p>${news.date}</p>
                `;

          // Добавляем ссылку на новость
          newsItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.location.href = news.link; // Перенос на страницу новости
          });

          newsContainer.appendChild(newsItem);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching articles.json:', error));

    // Событие для случайной статьи
    document.getElementById('random-article').addEventListener('click', function() {
      fetch('/pages.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          const randomArticle = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
          window.location.href = randomArticle.link;
        });
    });

    // Событие для случайной новости
    document.getElementById('random-news').addEventListener('click', function() {
      fetch('/articles.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          const randomNews = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
          window.location.href = randomNews.link;
        });
    });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        const mainContent = document.querySelector('.main-content');
        const exploreSection = document.querySelector('.section-container');
        const leftSidebar = document.querySelector('.left-sidebar');
        const rightSidebar = document.querySelector('.right-sidebar');

        const main = document.querySelector('main');
        main.innerHTML = '';

        main.appendChild(mainContent);
        main.appendChild(exploreSection);
        main.appendChild(leftSidebar);
        main.appendChild(rightSidebar);
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>



I tried to solve this problem using Chat GPT, but everything it suggested did not help me.
I tried to fix some styles, but everything I tried didn't help either.

what is in style.css? Unless you are writing a library when I see !important it often indicates too much CSS and need for less css to fight against itself

Try to remove the need for the JavaScript to get data in your question and try to simplify this "debug my code for me" type question to something much smaller

The issue is caused by the excessive margin-top: 600px !important on the footer and overflow: hidden in the @media (max-width: 768px) styles. Removing the margin and the overflow: hidden property fixes it. Also, avoid overusing !important, as it makes CSS harder to maintain. See the attached screenshot mobile screenshot

Please improve the formatting of your answer, code belongs in a code block
